# get json value and display based on div using id

Tags: php, laravel-5

I had json like this :

Example :  this is my collection object

```
$jobs_list = Jobs::where('enterprise_id', $user->id)->get();
```

In my view page i created one foreach loop and i displayed all values based on current user details. now i created one database condition like:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('jobs', 'users.id', '=', 'jobs.created_by')
        ->select('users.first_name as created_by','jobs.id')
        ->where('jobs.enterprise_id', $user->id)
        ->get();**
```

output :

```
[{
    "created_by": "sivarajummani",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "created_by": "sivarajummani",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "created_by": "sivarajummani",
    "id": 4
}, {
    "created_by": "sivarajummani",
    "id": 5
}]
```

This id is there in collection itself. so i need to know how to display these value in html file.

Comment: please provide the proper explanation where exactly you want o display that information?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: _"I had one array collection also"_ - Ok? We still have no clue what you're actually asking. _"this json value"_ - You got several json values. _"based on div using id"_ - What divs?

Comment: that array collection i displayed on my view file . so i can't merge these json and display in view file .

Comment: Merge what? You've only showed us one array. Are you trying to display this using PHP or JS in the front end? What should the end result look like? Where does it come from? Do you get it through Ajax or passing this (a json string) to the view from your controller? What have you tried? There are still too many unanswered questions...

Comment: Where's your code for the view? Where is the code that creates the view and passes the `$users` collection?